# Should my css reset go before or after my css code?

Tags: css

I'm not familiar with how css parses the style block so does the first style definition on an element get applied or the last. I might want padding on an element but in the reset I'm using the padding on all elements is set to 0. Simple example:

```
<style>
body
{
   opacity: 0;
}
body
{
   opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

I've had varying results on different browsers so I'm not sure where to put the reset so it works across all browsers.

Comment: a stylesheet prioritizes as it progresses, among many other qualifying rules. In your case, do the reset first.

Comment: First, by the way, a good thing to you to read: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: @KaiQing, thank you, could you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Great link @ToniAlmeida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS prioritizes as it progresses, as well as by a scoring method that can be reviewed in Toni's comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

You would do your reset first, then override your styles as you progress in the stylesheet. Consider the rules in that link to fully understand how css will score the selectors.

Also, Sadaj has a good suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

Put it before all the other stylesheets

and

do an import

example:

```
@import url("resetstyle.css");
```

From comments as suggested by almeida go through http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/